# autoenablesDefaultLighting is too bright in iOS 12 and SCNView.pointOfView is not effective

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, ios12, sceneview, scnlight

I am using SceneKit’s `autoenablesDefaultLighting` and `allowsCameraControl` functions of my sceneView to provide light to an obj 3D model in the app and rotate around this object in Objective-C. Since upgrading to iOS12, the default light intensity of `autoenablesDefaultLighting` gets higher and the 3D model looks so bright!

Did anyone faced the same issue? If yes, is there a way to control the light intensity of `autoenablesDefaultLighting` when its value is ‘YES’? If it is not editable, I tried to attach/constraint an omni light or directional light to a camera by creating a node, assign a light to this node and add as child of `SCNView.pointOfView` but no light illuminates the scene.

Exemple:
[3D object displayed before iOS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bve0h.jpg)
[3D object displayed in iOS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKDfH.jpg)

It will be good if anyone can help me on it.

Many thanks!

**Edit to solve this issue**

I create a new SCNCamera and add this in a node and set the PointOfView of my scnView. 
Activate the HDR of this camera with `scnView.pointOfView.wantHDR = YES;`
but a had a grey background.

To delete the grey background I delete the background color with `scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor]`
and set the explosure of the camera to -1 with :

`self.scnView.pointOfView.camera.minimumExposure = -1;`
`self.scnView.pointOfView.camera.maximumExposure = -1;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try enabling HDR. It should result in a balanced exposure

`scnView?.pointOfView?.camera?.wantsHDR = true`

With HDR enabled, you can even control exposure compensation with

`scnView?.pointOfView?.camera?.exposureOffset`

Comment: Thanks for your answer i try this and it work !!! but i have now a grey background even if i set : `self.scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Not sure why you are getting a grey background. I hope you haven't added any light source of your own, because that could disable the default lighting.

"If you change the value to true, SceneKit automatically adds and places an omnidirectional light source when rendering scenes that contain no lights or only contain ambient lights." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523812-autoenablesdefaultlighting

As a workaround, you can also try using clear color and adding a white view behind the scnView.

Answer (score 1):

.camera?.wantsHDR = true

.camera?.wantsExposureAdaptation = false

Should solve the problem!