# Bright model in scene kit iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have a problem with 3D model in SceneKit. I also use maxstARobjec After updating to iOS 12 it's start looking brighter than before ([SCREENSHOTS WITH THE SAME ISSUE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542734/autoenablesdefaultlighting-is-too-bright-in-ios-12-and-scnview-pointofview-is-no))

I use 2 light node, without *autoenablesDefaultLighting*.
And one more fact about this issue: when I hide all lights the model (which must be black) is grey like it's has extra light...

Sorry for my bad language, and I very need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the same issue by convert .obj file to .scn files in Xcode, and use this scenes as nodes. Editor -> Convert to SceneKit file format (.scn)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukdi9.png)